# Field Oriented Control for ACIM

Tags: induction-motor, vector-control

I was working on developing software for controlling torque and speed of 3 Phase AC Induction Motors using Field Oriented Control aka Vector Control.

My motor has following details as per the nameplate:

Rated Power : 3 kW
Rated Voltage : 48VAC
Rated Current : 54Arms
Rated Speed : 2660 RPM
Poles : 4
Make : Nidec
Max. Speed = 6000 rpm.

I have tested my software for no load speed control upto 3000 rpm . I have kept magnetizing command current to be around 20A.

My motor consumes 2.5A DC and 14Arms ac current at 3000 rpm.

I am doing calculations in pu system where 1pu = 32767.

I observed that initially , output variablea VD and VQ both are positive , but as speed ramps up , VQ keeps increasing upto 0.75*pu but VD reduces and even goes in negative. (from 0.125pu to - 0.125*PU.

Kindly help me in concluding my observations.

Comment: What's the question? Is there a specific value you want?

Comment: VQ is the controller output which regulates Torque and VD regulates Flux. Values of VQ and VD varies between -32767 to 32767  . Is it OK for VD to go from positive values to negative values. Same behaviour ain't observed for VQ. I have been working on FOC for a year now but still need to learn a lot from mathematical vector transformations.

Comment: Does the thing work, and do you have the means to measure the performance of the motor? If it works, then probably you’re not doing anything totally wrong.

Comment: Yes it's  working. I limited phase currents at 46Arms in algorithm . I made motor to run at 600 rpm and then stopped rotor using my hands. Using clamp meter , I observed motor currents limited at 46Arms